# Font decoding problem by importing records from a table in a DB2 database into IBM Lotus Notes documents using a Lotuscript code agent

Tags: import, db2, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have an agent written in Lotuscript (IBM Domino 9.0.1 - Windows 10) that reads records into a DB2 database and writes them to Notes documents. The table in DB2 (Centos OS) contains international names in Varchar fields such as "Łódź".
The DB2 database was created as UTF-8 CodePage: 1208 and Domino by its nature supports UNICODE. Unfortunately, the value loaded in the notes document is not "Łódź" as it should be but it is "? Ód?".

How can I import special characters from DB2
in Domino NSF DBs in correct ways?
Thank you

To import the table I used the following code taken from OpenNtfs XSnippets:

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=db2-run-from-lotusscript-into-notes-form

Comment: Find where the codepage conversion is happening. Alter the lotusscript to dump the hex of the received data for the column-concerned to a file or in a dialog-box. If the hex codes differ from what is in the column, then it may be your Db2-client that is using the wrong codepage. Are you aware of the DB2CODEPAGE environment variable for Windows? That might help if it is the Db2-client that is doing the codepage conversion.

Comment: Maybe setting "Text file encoding" to "Other:UTF-8" in Designer-File-Preferences-General-Workspace helps.

Comment: Thanks mao was that setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find where the codepage conversion is happening. Alter the lotusscript to dump the hex of the received data for the column-concerned to a file or in a dialog-box. If the hex codes differ from what is in the column, then it may be your Db2-client that is using the wrong codepage. Are you aware of the DB2CODEPAGE environment variable for Windows? That might help if it is the Db2-client that is doing the codepage conversion.

i.e setting environment variable DB2CODEPAGE=1208 may help, although careful testing is required to ensure it does not cause other symptoms that are mentioned online.

Comment: If I recall correctly, LotusScript assumes UTF-16.  There's a reference database that I created many years ago posted on OpenNTF. It contains the LMBCS, UTF-8 and UTF-16 values for all Unicode chars. (Well, all that existed at that time.)  This can help you interpret the data that you dump as hex. Link to the download is here: https://openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/CodeByDate/CE6B55B6B4A04A6E862576E10008B911

Comment: Here's an example of the data. StackOverflow compresses it all into one line, unfortunately. Just one randomly chosen record:  ₠


Unicode UTF16 Hex Value 20 A0
Unicode UTF16 Decimal Value 8352
Unicode UTF8 Value E2 82 A0
Name EURO-CURRENCY SIGN
Category Sc
Canonical Combining Classes 0
Bi-Directional Category ET
Decomposition Mapping 
Decimal Digit Value 
DigitValue 
Numeric Value 
Mirrored N
Name (Unicode 1.0) 
ISO 10646 Comment 
Uppercase Mapping 
Lowercase Mapping 
Titlecase Mapping 
 
LMBCS: 14 20 A0